# Stored procedure with no parameters to update the database table

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure that has some parameters but the column I need to use is not a parameter and I need to update it when the date is changed which I'm using a date picker. I am not sure how to call this in C# the field I need to use is called `[completiondt]`.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_load_status_update]
    @id INT = 0,
    @statusname VARCHAR(128) = '',
    @loginname VARCHAR(512)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @today DATETIME = [dbo].[fnc_getdatelocal]()
    DECLARE @statusid INT
    DECLARE @oldstatusid INT
    DECLARE @olddriverid INT

    SELECT @statusid = [id] 
    FROM [LoadStatus] 
    WHERE [name] = @statusname

    SELECT @oldstatusid = [statusid], @olddriverid = [driverid] 
    FROM [Load] 
    WHERE [id] = @id

    -- update status, and reset driverid to null if it is back to pending
    UPDATE [Load] 
    SET [statusid] = ISNULL(@statusid, 0),
        [driverid] = CASE 
                        WHEN ISNULL(@statusid, 0) = 0 
                           THEN NULL
                           ELSE [driverid] 
                     END
    WHERE [id] = @id

    --kludge for now, need to update status on each row in the future
    UPDATE [LoadContact] 
    SET [statusid] = IsNull(@statusid, 0),
        [completiondt] = CASE
                            WHEN [instancetype] = 1 
                                 AND ISNULL(@oldstatusid, 0) < 3 
                                 AND ISNULL(@statusid, 0) >= 3 
                               THEN @today
                            WHEN [instancetype] = 2 
                                 AND ISNULL(@oldstatusid, 0) < 4 
                                 AND ISNULL(@statusid, 0) >= 4 
                               THEN @today
                            ELSE [completiondt]
                         END
    WHERE [loadid] = @id

    --kludge for now, need to update order invoice status separately
    IF (ISNULL(@statusid, 0) >= 8)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [Invoice] 
        SET [statusid] = 8
        WHERE [orderid] = @id

        UPDATE [Bill] 
        SET [statusid] = 8
        WHERE [loadid] = @id
    END
```

C# code:

```
protected void editDeliveredDate_DateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        ASPxDateEdit dateEdit = sender as ASPxDateEdit;
        DateTime currentDate = dateEdit.Date;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ACAOSBConnectionString"].ToString()))
        {
            string ordstr = (txt_orderid.Text != null) ? txt_orderid.Text : string.Empty;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "usp_load_status_update";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ordstr.ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@loginname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 512).Value = Page.User.Identity.Name;

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //TODO: save log for now;
                int ex_errorid = 0;
                string ex_msg = string.Concat((ex != null && ex.Message != null) ? ex.Message.ToString() : (ex != null && ex.InnerException != null) ? ex.InnerException.ToString() : "No Message Found ", (ex != null && ex.StackTrace != null) ? ex.StackTrace.ToString() : "No Strack Trace ");
                int ex_genericid = 0;
                string ex_username = (Page != null && Page.User != null && Page.User.Identity != null && Page.User.Identity.Name != null) ? Page.User.Identity.Name : "No user found";
                Jobs.log_somewhere ex_errorlog = new Jobs.log_somewhere();
                ex_errorlog.log_secos_error(ex_errorid, ex_msg, ex_genericid, ex_username);
            }
        }
    }
```

Once I figure this out it will be equal to `currentDate`.

Comment: I don't understand the question because it looks like you already have an example to follow with the code you posted.

Comment: I am not sure how to call [completiondt] since it is not a parameter that is the field I need to update

Comment: Add the parameter to your SQL using `@Id` in your stored procedure as an example, set the SQL type for this new parameter according to the type needed based on the SQL field type in your table definition, update your SQL `UPDATE` statement to set this value. In your C#, add the parameter, again using the `@Id` parameter in your C# as an example and set the type according to how you typed the SQL parameter in you stored procedure.

Comment: I think the bottom line here is that you need to be able to modify the SQL procedure. Are you able to do that? Because it doesn't sound like you are considering that for some reason.

Comment: You don't call a column. You update it, with an update statement that should include a where clause to limit the update to certain row(s). Kind of like all the other update statements you already have. Not sure what the question really is here.

Comment: My question is how do I get the value of currentDate in that completiondt field

Comment: The same way all your other updates are working. Update YourTable set MyColumn = MyValue Where MyKey = SomeKey We don't even know what table it belongs to. Your procedure updates several tables already. Just add another column to the appropriate update statement.

Comment: From the stored procedure code `completiondt` looks like some kind of audit field recording when an action took place. Perhaps you should not be trying to inject a particular date into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to take a stab at answering your question, whether or not this will work for you depends your ultimate goal and your applications requirements.

Comments have been added in the code where I've made changes.

---

First, I've added a new SQL parameter `@datecompleted` with a default value of NULL. This will allow you to exclude it when calling the sproc from C# and continue to use existing SQL logic if necessary.

Second, I've added a `COALESCE` call to use the `@datecompleted` value if it's not NULL or call the function `fnc_getdatelocal` as it does already if it is NULL.

SQL:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_load_status_update]
    @id INT = 0,
    @statusname VARCHAR(128) = '',
    @loginname VARCHAR(512),
    @datecompleted DATETIME = NULL -- Added new SQL parameter for date completed input from C#
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Set the @today variable to use the @datecompleted paramter if it's not null otherwise use date from the fnc_getdatelocal() function
    DECLARE @today DATETIME = COALESCE(@datecompleted,[dbo].[fnc_getdatelocal]())
    -- Depending on the locality of the @datecompleted parameter and your application's requirements, 
    --   you will need to figure out the best way for your process to convert to locality used by the fnc_getdatelocal function
    -- Does your function accept a parameter, if so you may be able to pass the @datecompleted parameter to it, e.g.  DECLARE @today DATETIME = COALESCE(@datecompleted,[dbo].[fnc_getdatelocal](@datecompleted))

    DECLARE @statusid INT
    DECLARE @oldstatusid INT
    DECLARE @olddriverid INT

    SELECT @statusid = [id] 
    FROM [LoadStatus] 
    WHERE [name] = @statusname

    SELECT @oldstatusid = [statusid], @olddriverid = [driverid] 
    FROM [Load] 
    WHERE [id] = @id

    -- update status, and reset driverid to null if it is back to pending
    UPDATE [Load] 
    SET [statusid] = ISNULL(@statusid, 0),
        [driverid] = CASE 
                        WHEN ISNULL(@statusid, 0) = 0 
                           THEN NULL
                           ELSE [driverid] 
                     END
    WHERE [id] = @id

    --kludge for now, need to update status on each row in the future
    UPDATE [LoadContact] 
    SET [statusid] = IsNull(@statusid, 0),
    [completiondt] = CASE
                        WHEN [instancetype] = 1 
                             AND ISNULL(@oldstatusid, 0) < 3 
                             AND ISNULL(@statusid, 0) >= 3 
                           THEN @today
                        WHEN [instancetype] = 2 
                             AND ISNULL(@oldstatusid, 0) < 4 
                             AND ISNULL(@statusid, 0) >= 4 
                           THEN @today
                        ELSE [completiondt]
                     END
    WHERE [loadid] = @id

    --kludge for now, need to update order invoice status separately
    IF (ISNULL(@statusid, 0) >= 8)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [Invoice] 
        SET [statusid] = 8
        WHERE [orderid] = @id

        UPDATE [Bill] 
        SET [statusid] = 8
        WHERE [loadid] = @id
    END
```

---

C#:

I've changed your `currentDate`'s variable type to allow it to be null. This can be useful if you don't always want to send it in your SQL call and instead use the existing logic as it is today. I believe the `ASPxDateEdit` control can have a `null` date if configured for it. This really depends on your requirements.

```
protected void editDeliveredDate_DateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ASPxDateEdit dateEdit = sender as ASPxDateEdit;
    // I made your currentDate variable to be nullable
    DateTime? currentDate = dateEdit.Date; 

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ACAOSBConnectionString"].ToString()))
    {
        string ordstr = (txt_orderid.Text != null) ? txt_orderid.Text : string.Empty;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "usp_load_status_update";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ordstr.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@loginname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 512).Value = Page.User.Identity.Name;
        if(currentDate != null)
        { 
            // only set the parameter if it's not null, this will allow the SQL sproc to use its existing logic        
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@datecompleted", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = currentDate;
        }

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO: save log for now;
            int ex_errorid = 0;
            string ex_msg = string.Concat((ex != null && ex.Message != null) ? ex.Message.ToString() : (ex != null && ex.InnerException != null) ? ex.InnerException.ToString() : "No Message Found ", (ex != null && ex.StackTrace != null) ? ex.StackTrace.ToString() : "No Strack Trace ");
            int ex_genericid = 0;
            string ex_username = (Page != null && Page.User != null && Page.User.Identity != null && Page.User.Identity.Name != null) ? Page.User.Identity.Name : "No user found";
            Jobs.log_somewhere ex_errorlog = new Jobs.log_somewhere();
            ex_errorlog.log_secos_error(ex_errorid, ex_msg, ex_genericid, ex_username);
        }
    }
}
```